# How to customize date format in ArcGIS Operation Dashboard's list widget?

Tags: arcgis-online, operations-dashboard

I'm trying to add to my dashboard a list widget to show a list of recently updated records. I'm able to easily add fields by putting the field name between braces (ex `{LastEditDate}`), like in arcGIS Javascript API's `PopupTemplate`.

[image]

What I want to do now is to customize the date format. In this case only the time is relevant, but in other cases I might want only the date.

I tried to use a syntax similar to javascript API (`{LastEditDate:DateFormat(selector: 'date', fullYear: true)}`), without success.

Is there a way to customize a field's date format in the list widget?

Comment: Once they integrate Arcade compatibility this will be easy, as of now I do not think there is a way

Comment: I just tried to edit the back-end JSON of the dashboard as a test of one of mine, using the syntax in your answer. It didn't work, but maybe you could bang at it a little more than I did. Make a copy or use a test app, you have the potential to destroy your content.  https://ago-assistant.esri.com/

Answer (score 2):

The date format for any date field used in an Ops Dashboard widget is inherited from the pop-up config of that layer in the webmap.

[image]

Comment: Nice! Thank you for this. Would be nice if YYYYMMDD were an option.